# Solving a system of equations for x that contains $x^Tx$ (where x is a vector)

Tags: matrices, optimization, systems-of-equations, matrix-calculus

So I may as well be a complete novice as far as math goes, but I need to solve a system of equations that contains some matrix multiplications. Sorry for lack of background knowledge / difficulty understanding.

I have two variables, $L$ and $x$. $L$ is a scalar and 
$x$ is a column vector. There is a "known" constant $c$ that has the same dimensions as $x$. Additionally, I have a "known" square symmetric matrix $Q$. This matrix $Q$ is positive-definite, but I don't think that's relevant to solving the system of equations.

So I need to solve for the two unknowns $L$ and $x$ in terms of the other values in the following equations:

$c^T - (2*L*x^TQ) = 0$

$1 = x^TQx$

So if $x$ and $Q$ were just scalars, this would be really simple. You could divide the second equation by $Q$ and take the square root, but is something analogous to that even possible with the matrix multiplications?

Sorry again for lack of knowledge.

Comment: In my original comment, I didn't notice that $L$ is also variable we're trying to solve for, not a constant. See my answer below for a full solution.

Comment: Ok, so now it seems that substituting into the second equation gives a huge matrix multiplication that I'm having trouble resolving. It seems like  you get something massive like this:

$1 = (\frac{1}{2L} (Q)^{-1}c)^T * Q * \frac{1}{2L} (Q)^{-1}c$

$4L^2 = c^TQ^{-1T} * Q * Q^-1c$

I'm guessing the two of the Q's cancel out here? 

$4L^2 = c^T * Q^-1 * c$

Now the right hand side is technically a scalar?

$L = +/- \frac{1}{2}sqrt(c^T * Q^-1 *c)$

Comment: Yes, that's right, the right hand side is a scalar because (assuming $Q$ is an $n \times n$ matrix) $c^T$ is $1 \times n$, and $c$ is $n \times 1$, so the dimension of the result is $(1 \times n) (n \times n)(n \times 1) = 1 \times 1$.

Comment: Yes, note that $(Q^{-1})^T = Q^{-1}$ since $Q$ is symmetric (and therefore $Q^{-1}$ is also symmetric). So $(Q^{-1})^T Q Q^{-1} = Q^{-1}QQ^{-1} = Q^{-1}$ (cancel $Q$ with its inverse on whichever side you like).

Comment: I see, I didn't think about the symmetry removing the transposes at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equation is equivalent to $2LQ^T x = c$, or $Q^T x = \frac{1}{2L}c$. Since $Q$ is symmetric, this simplifies to $Qx = \frac{1}{2L}c$. Assuming $Q$ is strictly positive definite ($x^T Q x > 0$ for all nonzero $x$), it follows that $Q$ is invertible. Therefore, $x = \frac{1}{2L}Q^{-1}c$ is the unique solution to the first equation.

Plugging this solution into the second equation gives us

$$\begin{aligned}
x^T Q x
&= \left(\frac{1}{2L}Q^{-1}c\right)^T Q \left(\frac{1}{2L}Q^{-1}c\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{4L^2}c^T Q^{-1} Q Q^{-1}c \\
&= \frac{1}{4L^2}c^T Q^{-1} c \\
\end{aligned}$$
where we have used the fact that the transpose of $Q^{-1}$ is still $Q^{-1}$, since $Q$ is symmetric.

We want to find the value of $L$ which makes this equal to $1$:
$$\frac{1}{4L^2}c^T Q^{-1} c = 1$$
Multiplying both sides by $L$ and taking the square root gives us
$$L = \pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{c^T Q^{-1} c}$$
Note that the square root on the right hand side is a real number since $c^T Q c > 0$ (because $Q$ is positive definite).

Comment: Oh ok, so this seems equivalent to the value I derived in my extremely messy comments above. 

We know $x = \frac{1}{2L}Q^{-1}c$, so we can plug L back in here to get the two x values. So ultimately we ended up solving the 'squared vector' problem via the scalar L?

Comment: Yes, everything in the equation $\frac{1}{4L^2}c^T Q^{-1}c = 1$ is a constant except for $L$, and since $L$ is a scalar we can just multiply both sides by $L^2$ and take the square root.